# How do I run this code without clicking on the extension button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to run this code without having to click on the `chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener`. How do I do this?

This is the code:

```
var ToggleJSApplication = {

  triggerWin: null,
  urlPattern: 'http://*',

  init: function() {
    var self = this;
    self.updateIcon(function() {
      chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(self.toggleState.bind(self));
      chrome.windows.onFocusChanged.addListener(self.onWinFocusChanged.bind(self));
    });
  },

  getState: function(incognito, callback) {
    var self = this,
        data = {
          'primaryUrl': self.urlPattern,
          'incognito': incognito || false
        };

    chrome.contentSettings.javascript.get(data, function(state) {
      state.enabled = (state.setting === 'allow');
      if (typeof callback === 'function') callback(state);
    });
  },

  setState: function(incognito, enabled, callback) {
    var self = this,
        data = {
          'primaryPattern': '<all_urls>',
          'setting': (enabled) ? 'allow' : 'block',
          'scope': (incognito === true) ? 'incognito_session_only' : 'regular'
        };

    chrome.contentSettings.javascript.set(data, function() {
      self.updateIcon();
      if (typeof callback === 'function') callback();
    });
  },

  toggleState: function() {
    var self = this;
    chrome.windows.getCurrent(function(win) {
      self.triggerWin = win;
      self.getState(win.incognito, function(state) {
        self.setState(win.incognito, !state.enabled, function() {
          self.reloadCurrentTab();
        });
      });
    });
  },

  onWinFocusChanged: function() {
    var self = this;
    chrome.windows.getCurrent(function(win) {
      self.triggerWin = win;
      self.updateIcon();
    });
  },

  reloadCurrentTab: function() {
    chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true}, function(tabs) {
      var tab = tabs[0];
      chrome.tabs.duplicate(tab.id);
      chrome.tabs.remove(tab.id);
    });
  },

  updateIcon: function(callback) {
    var self = this,
        incognito = (self.triggerWin && self.triggerWin.incognito) || false;

    self.getState(incognito, function(state) {
      if (state.enabled) {
        chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path: 'icons/38-on.png'});
        chrome.browserAction.setTitle({title: 'JavaScript is enabled'});
      }
      else {
        chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path: 'icons/38-off.png'});
        chrome.browserAction.setTitle({title: 'JavaScript is disabled'});
      }

      if (typeof callback === 'function') callback();
    });
  }

};

ToggleJSApplication.init();
```

I already tried using context menu's but I failed. Is there any workaround?

Comment: Clicking the browser action just executes `ToggleJSApplication.toggleState()`.  So running the code without clicking the browser action would be a matter of ending your script with `ToggleJSApplication.toggleState();`.  I think you want something more complicated, but it's not clear to me what that would be.  In what situation are you wanting your script to execute?

Comment: @Teepeemm Basically If i click on a button, then all of the above code should run.

Comment: @Teepeemm I just tried your ToggleJSApplication.toggleState(); and it works!! ty. Do you mind typing it in an answer so that i can mark it as the right answer

Comment: I'm still not sure what you're trying to do.  If you want a button click to activate things, then a browser action is the way to go.  If you want everything to happen without user intervention, then you can end your script the way I said.  If you want a button click that isn't the browser action, then it sounds like you're wanting to click a button located in the webpage, in which case you'd want a content script to attach a listener to that button and use message passing.

Comment: @Teepeemm, Yeah I was trying to click a button in the webpage to run the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mentioned that you want to use a button click in the existing webpage to trigger your script.  In order to interact with the webpage, you need to use a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts), which must interact with the background script via [message passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging).  The content script can be as simple as:

```
document.getElementById('buttonId').addEventListener('click',sendMessage);
// or $('#buttonId').click(sendMessage);

function sendMessage() {
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({'message':'buttonClicked'});
}
```

Then in your background script, you can add:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(messageListener);

function messageListener(request) {
    if ( request.message === 'buttonClicked' ) {
        ToggleJSApplication.toggleState();
    }
}
```